# Monitoring UIImageView for image property change

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

How can I detect if `UIImageview` is changed, and how can I show `NSLog` when image is changed? Here is my code:

```
-(void)changePhotoStatus
{
    NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"FasterText.png"],[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Don'tTouchText.png"],nil];

    fasttext.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[myArray objectAtIndex:arc4random() % [myArray count]]];

    if (fasttext.image == [UIImage imageNamed:@"Don'tToucText.png"]) {
        NSLog(@"cahn");
    }
}
```

I use `NSTimer` to call changes of image. But `NSLog` won't appear. Help please.

Comment: Check your nstimer code carefully. or post it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(changePhotoStatus) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

When you are done with changing image, don't forget to `invalidate` the timer.

Comment: You don't need to invalidate the timer if it fires. Only if you want to prevent it from firing.

Comment: @CameronLowellPalmer Plz check this post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499040/invalidating-an-nstimer

Comment: That post is almost an exact copy of Apple's Timer Programming Topics.  https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Articles/usingTimers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000807-CJBJCBDE and as it states, if it is repeating you will need to invalidate it yourself. However, invalidating it depends on the situation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use key value coding as follows

```
- (void)registerSelfAsObserverForImageView
 {
    [imageView addObserver:self
                forKeyPath:@"image"
                   options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew |
                            NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld)
                context:NULL];
}


- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                      ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change
                       context:(void *)context 
{
    // Put your code here to handle event of the imageview (object) changing value :)

    [super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath
                         ofObject:object
                           change:change
                          context:context];
}
```

Don't forget to deregister in dealloc or when you don't need updates anymore

```
- (void)unregisterForChangeNotification
 {
     [imageView removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"image"];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, assuming you have setup the view file properly...

```
#import "JDemoViewController.h"

@interface JDemoViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *imageNameArray;

- (void) handleTimerEventFired;

@end

@implementation JDemoViewController

@synthesize imageView = _imageView;
@synthesize imageNameArray = _imageNameArray;

- (void) dealloc
{
    self.imageView = nil;
    self.imageNameArray = nil;
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.imageNameArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"img1",@"img2",@"img3",@"img4", nil];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2 target:self selector:@selector(handleTimerEventFired) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (void) handleTimerEventFired
{    
    NSString *tempImageName = [self.imageNameArray objectAtIndex:(arc4random()%4)];

    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:tempImageName];

    self.imageView.image = image;

    if(tempImageName == @"img3")
    {
        NSLog(@"Image 3 was Loaded !");
    }

}

@end
```